# Your debugged process might be corrupted and restaring it is recommended

Tags: c#, devexpress, maui, hot-reload

I'm developing a .NET MAUI App using DevExpress.  It was working nicely and **Hot Reload** was fine but for some odd reason I keep getting this error message:

[image: Hot Reload - Error]

This happens only on C# and nothing else.  If add/edit code on XAML files it works fine and no problems at all.  Any workaround with this issue?

Comment: Reboot PC. Delete `bin` and `obj` folders. If you are attempting to edit the c# code while debugging, that is quite new; perhaps it is not reliable yet. Also, I would only attempt c# edit when debugging on Windows; if you are running on a mobile emulator or device, stop the app to edit c# code, then launch it again.

Comment: I've done this but still doesn't work.  It could be that it's because a mobile emulator but I do recall it was working fine before.  I know if I do this on Windows it works but why not on mobile? If XAML works fine then C# should the same.

Comment: *"If XAML works fine then C# should the same. "* err, no.`xaml` is parsed into an internal form that is much easier for debugger to change without restarting app, than c# code. This is especially true on mobile, because the app is running on top of an OS that was not developed with .Net in mind; this affects "code" more than it does "xaml" (which can be executed by an interpreter). I do understand that recently the ability to edit c# w/o restart was implemented, but I am not surprised that it isn't supported well on Android. Nor would I be surprised if it is still buggy on Windows.